# What's Docker easiest way to deploy Rails on production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, docker

I'm interested in **Docker** as it creates a neat way of setting up an application environment.

EDIT : I'm on **Digital Ocean Droplet** created with their [Docker 1 click Application](https://www.digitalocean.com/products/one-click-apps/docker/).

<del>Apparently there isn't a proper way to deploy a Rails application to production, or at least I haven't found it. The setup seems much more complicated then setting up the server from scratch and using Capistrano. I tried using Heroku but it doesn't entirely support Docker.</del>

---

**Is there any good guideline on how to setup Docker to deploy a simple Rails application on a production server?**

---

I read/watched already this references:

- The [Quickstart: Docker Compose and Rails](https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/) is ok for development, but then [Using Compose in production](https://docs.docker.com/compose/production/) is too rough and superficial.
- [The Docker for DevOps course: From development to pro](https://www.udemy.com/the-docker-for-devops-course-from-development-to-production/learn/v4/)
  way too complex, but is the only that at the end tells you how to deploy Rails on Digital Ocean. Anyway there must be an easier way.
- [Deploying Your Docker Rails App](https://blog.codeship.com/deploying-docker-rails-app/)
  is just for Heroku.
- [Getting to know Centurion](https://blog.newrelic.com/2014/08/12/docker-centurion/)
  does anyone use Centurion to deploy?
- [Docker + Capistrano = Warp Speed](http://rockyj.in/2015/09/06/docker_capistrano.html)
  a bit buggy and outdated.
- [Running multiple web applications on a Docker host with Apache](https://medium.com/@jmarhee/running-multiple-web-applications-on-a-docker-host-with-apache-85f673f02803#.rqrholeaf)
  the right approach, shame is not for Rails..

Comment: What do you mean with *proper way to deploy*?

Comment: I belive that a minimal Rails application have a default way of beign deployed on a server. Heroku has his own [Getting Started guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4) so that at least you know how to successfully do default deploy, whereas Docker leaves you alone so the only way is to try and figure out everything by yourself.

Comment: I've found [this guide](https://medium.com/@jmarhee/running-multiple-web-applications-on-a-docker-host-with-apache-85f673f02803#.p78ip4x07) pretty useful as keeps everything clear and simple. It's for PHP applications though.

Comment: The question is still not clear (as someone has already cast a close vote). Where do you want to deploy it? Heroku? Docker cloud?

Comment: I am on a Digital Ocean Droplet with Ubuntu Docker 1.11.2 on 14.04. I updated the question. My guess is this technology is too new and no one has written a simple yet effective guide. I'm studying a solution and as soon as I have I'll try to write my experience on the matter.